# Forward packets on different private IPs and interface aliasing

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, routing

I have a server with 2 public IPs. I configured interface aliasing to hold the second IP:

```
# ifconfig
vmbr0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:4f:18:5f  
          inet addr:public.ip.number.1 Bcast:x.x.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

vmbr0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:4f:18:5f  
          inet addr:public.ip.number.2  Bcast:x.x.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I would like using iptables to redirect traffic on vmbr0 port 80 to 10.0.0.100 and traffic on vmbr0:0 port 80 to 10.0.0.101.

What I tried:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to public.ip.number.1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o vmbr0:0 -j SNAT --to public.ip.number.2
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.100:80
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0:0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.101:80
```

But all traffic goes to 10.0.0.100:80 whether I use one or the other public IP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can distinguish between logical interfaces that way.  Try instead

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d public.ip.number.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.100:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d public.ip.number.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.101:80
```

for the `DNAT` rules.  I have no idea what to do about the other pair, because they make no *sense*.  They apparently want to set the source address based on what virtual interface the packet goes out - but the choice of which virtual interface it goes out will depend on the source address!  If they are supposed to fix the "return half" packets from traffic that came in via the DNAT rule, then don't worry, the kernel will do that for you.

Comment: About the 2 SNAT rules, you mean they are not necessary ?

Comment: **If** they are there to deal with packets returning from the `DNAT` rules, then yes, they are not necessary.